# Restrict access to admin pages by IP from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to lock down a Drupal 7 site so that only users on a certain range of IPs can login. I tried using the Restrict IP module to block the /user and ?q=user routes but this did not work. Is there a way to do this with .htaccess and if so can someone point me in the right direction please?